# Categorical variable and Logistic regression model

Tags: regression, logistic, stata, categorical-encoding

I am trying to run a logit model with different types of independent variables like dummy, continuous and categorical variables. But I am facing problems in the categorical variables. Here, my dependent variable binary "receiving service from MBBS doctor (1) and not receiving services from MBBS doctor (0) and to run this I have used occupation as a categorical a, b and c. But, here, in  the category c there have no people who receive service from the MBBS doctor. Due to this, the Stata shows this category of variable as omitted. And, the stata also shows b as the reference category. In this situation what can I do?

Have any problems if I run this model in this way?